# Handling "No mapping found for HTTP request in DispatcherServlet" situation

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, exception, dispatcher

I've been trying to handle globally a situation when my dispatcher servlet doesn't have defined mapping for requested url but haven't found the solution yet.

Here's my class for handling global exceptions:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {

@Value("${exception.view.default}")
private String defaultExceptionView;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandlerController.class);

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView notFoundException(Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error ocurred: " + e.getMessage());
    return new ModelAndView(defaultExceptionView)
            .addObject("code", "404")
            .addObject("name", "Page Not Found")
            .addObject("message", "We couldn't find requested resource");
    }
}
```

I tried many different classes within @ExceptionHandler but nothing worked for me. The handler works fine - when I throw exception from one of the controllers and it isn't handled locally it goes straight to this global handler.

Is there a way to perform that kind of exception handling by @ControllerAdvice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, configure your `DispatcherServlet` with [`setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound-boolean-) which sets

> [...] whether to throw a `NoHandlerFoundException` when no `Handler` was
>   found for this request. This exception can then be caught with a
>   `HandlerExceptionResolver` or an `@ExceptionHandler` controller method.

and do what it says, ie. define an `@ExceptionHandler` for a `NoHandlerFoundException` exception.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Wasn't aware of that dispatcher config option.